# How to create shared package between Flutter project and Node/Typescript Cloud Functions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

We have a project built in Flutter with Dart in which all of the backend database calls are defined in the project source code. All of the database related calls are defined in a database.dart file.

We also have Firebase Cloud Functions built on Node.js with Typescript.

We are sending notifications to users using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). We have a need to share some code between our Flutter project and the Cloud Functions, as both sides may need to make the same backend calls and we don't want to duplicate our methods that make calls to the database, each of which may have multiple commands.

I did some research on this, and have not found a conclusive way to create a shared package between Flutter/Dart and Node.js/Typescript. I have seen a couple of packages potentially that may make JS interoperable with Dart, but nothing seems very clear or easily useable.

I think there are 2 main ways to approach this.

1. Create a shared API that both the Flutter project and the Cloud functions could call to run the database methods.
2. Somehow create a shared package that could be used in both the Flutter project and the Node.js project.
3. Move any shared methods into the Cloud Functions repo, and call those Cloud Functions in the Flutter code when needed.

Although 1 is a more scalable approach, I am not sure it is necessary for our use case and may be more than we really need. I would prefer a shared package of some sort, but is 2 even possible? 3 also seems like a viable option, but we already have all of the database calls in the Flutter repo so I was hoping to keep the way we are calling those methods somewhat uniform. If we move shared database calls to the Cloud Functions repo, then I will need to convert all of those methods in the Flutter project to make an HTTP call to Cloud Functions.

Thank you for any suggestions/recommendations/tips!